# The Specified GSHEET_JSON_URL does not contain JSON

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, google-sheets

I have a working Google Sheet JSON search engine here:

https://codepen.io/Teeke/pen/gOwgvXQ?editors=0011

It reads this Google sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c2aJmDdLkbjW0ErfUB0sfiQ-pt6zdW5KWZgREWs0zvM/edit#gid=0

I made an exact copy of the spreadsheet, and didn't change anything:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WUzfGeyOMVVOb8tbYLqHTrAk7Ii2p6l58EXG-kcgOcY/edit#gid=0

The codepen with the new spreadsheet raises the following error:

```
 The specified GSHEET_JSON_URL does not contain JSON:
```

https://codepen.io/Teeke/pen/zYKNRpZ?editors=0011

```
$(function() {
var GSHEET_JSON_URL = 
'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1WUzfGeyOMVVOb8tbYLqHTrAk7Ii2p6l58EXG- 
kcgOcY/1/public/values?alt=json';
```

The urls look exactly the same.

Comment: Did you fix it? I can't see the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to access your Google Sheets from an incognito window. Your first sheet is published while your second sheet is not.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The sheet needs to be published in order to be accessible.